# How do you change the font and font color in LaTeX (Anki)?

Tags: anki

I should preface this by saying I've had little to no exposure to LaTeX or Python until the past 24 hours where I've been trying madly trying to figure out what command, function, etc. means what! I've scoured countless threads as well which have helped but I'm afraid I'm stuck at this point. Apologies in advance if I'm misusing vocabulary!

I'm currently using Anki (2.1) to study for the MCAT and customized my cards to look a certain way. I wanted to edit the appearance of the LaTeX equations that I'm inputting (formulas I want to memorize) so that it looks neater on my cards. I managed to figure out how to make the background transparent (I installed the "Edit Latex build process" add-on) but I can't figure out how to change the font to something similar to a type-writer-ish font and how to change the font color to white (or at least some color I want).

In the header (preamble?) I've put:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setmainfont{lmtt}
\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\textcolor{white}
\begin{document}
```

At this point I have no idea if I'm even inputting code in the right place or not...

Any help would be very much appreciated – thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible template you can extend.  I tried to keep it pretty minimal while supporting the specific features you requested.  It’s possible to get a lot fancier.  This should be straightforward to add cards to, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Sets up the geometry of each page to fit on one of your cards:
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=3in]{geometry}
% Supports the same color names as HTML and CSS:
\usepackage[svgnames, Svgnames, HTML]{xcolor}
% Loads amsmath plus some extra stuff.
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Enables modern, Unicode fonts:
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Make all the fonts in the document match each other’s height:
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }

% I would not normally advise you to use a monospaced font as your main font,
% but if you want to, here is how:
\setmainfont{Anonymous Pro}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmonofont{Anonymous Pro}

% If you want to select a monospace font only some of the time, you might try
% the alltt package.

% You will also need a math font.  This sets the letters in math mode to the
% same as your text font, and declares a fallback for the rest:
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Anonymous Pro}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Anonymous Pro Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Anonymous Pro Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Anonymous Pro Bold Italic}

% You would declare your foreground and background colors here.

\begin{document}
\section*{\color{Navy}Trigonometric identities}

\begin{align*}
 &\text{SOH} & &\text{CAH} \\
   \sin^2 x &= 1 - \cos^2 x &
   \cos^2 x &= 1 - \sin^2 x \\
 \csc x &= \frac{1}{\sin x} &
   \sec x &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \\
 \sin (-x) &= - \sin x &
   \cos (-x) &= \cos x
\end{align*}
\clearpage

\section*{\color{Navy}Law of Sines and Cosines}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \( \frac{\sin \alpha}{\Alpha} = 
           \frac{\sin \beta}{\Beta} =
           \frac{\sin \gamma}{\Gamma} \)
  \item \( C^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB \cdot \cos c \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Card 1]

[image: Card 2]

Because it uses modern, Unicode fonts, it will only compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Although I don’t demonstrate it here, as you wouldn’t be able to see it in the sample images, `\nopagecolor` sets the background transparent, and you can put `\color{white}` sets the foreground color.  Both commands are from `xcolor`.

### For Backward-Compatibility

Since you don’t have the `anonymouspro` package and seem to be restricted to PDFLaTeX, here is a version using legacy packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Sets up the geometry of each page to fit on one of your cards:
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=3in]{geometry}
% Sets up the legacy 8-bit font encodings:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
% Loads some common math symbols.  Mostly overwritten by newtx.
\usepackage{amssymb}
% Loads newtx math with newtxtt as the default text font:
\usepackage[ttdefault]{newtxtt}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% Uses the text font for math symbols:
\usepackage{mathastext}
% Supports the same color names as HTML and CSS:
\usepackage[svgnames, Svgnames, HTML]{xcolor}
% Loads amsmath plus some extra stuff.
\usepackage{mathtools}
% If you need additional \mathscr, \mathcal, \mathfrak or \mathbb alphabets,
% consider loading mathalfa here.  This template also would need to load some
% extra packages to support Greek.

% You would declare your foreground and background colors here.

\begin{document}
\section*{\color{Navy}Trigonometric identities}

\begin{align*}
 &\text{SOH} & &\text{CAH} \\
   \sin^2 x &= 1 - \cos^2 x &
   \cos^2 x &= 1 - \sin^2 x \\
 \csc x &= \frac{1}{\sin x} &
   \sec x &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \\
 \sin (-x) &= - \sin x &
   \cos (-x) &= \cos x
\end{align*}
\clearpage

\section*{\color{Navy}Law of Sines and Cosines}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \( \frac{\sin a}{A} = 
           \frac{\sin b}{B} =
           \frac{\sin c}{C} \)
  \item \( C^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB \cdot \cos c \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Card 1]
[image: Card 2]

Comment: I put in the code as you've written but it's still not changing the appearance of any formulas I put in... I should also note I'm using a Mac (Anki says it uses LaTeX) so would that change anything?

Comment: @wuhoo Make sure you have [the `anonymouspro` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/anonymouspro) installed, that you’re compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`, and that you’re actually generating a new output file instead of failing with an error and not updating the PDF.

Comment: If you’re unable to use LuaTeX or XeTeX, the code I wrote could be adapted to PDFTeX with a few modifications to the preamble.

Comment: How do I install the anonymouspro package? Also, I'm not sure how to use lualatex or xelatex with Anki... how do I adapt it for pdftex? The error I'm getting is telling me that it can't be run with pdftex so I think I have to adapt it.

Comment: @wuhoo Okay, I’m not familiar with Anki, so I’d look in the settings for an option to run LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead. Your LaTeX distribution should come with a package manager, but you haven’t said what that is. I’ll get on a revised version when I have the chance.

Comment: Ah, I looked around online to see if there was a way to run anything other than LaTeX in Anki and found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/7t39mc/how_to_change_the_latex_compiler_anki_uses/. I typed in XeTeX instead of LaTeX within the command-line process for Anki (the ad-on lets me do this) so I think its running XeTeX but now the error I get is that it can't find the font but isn't the font already installed? I could try to install the font manually but I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: @wuhoo You can either download and install Anonymous Pro as a system font, or install the CTAN package with your package manager, or you can use whatever monospace font you do have installed; for example, Monaco.

Comment: @wuhoo I also added the PDFTeX-compatible solution you requested. But I recommend using the new toolchain when you can, and the legacy toolchain when you have to.

Comment: @wuhoo Anonymous Pro is here: https://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/anonymous-pro

Comment: Thank you for updating! I put in the code but now its telling me that \begindocument isn't there when it's clearly at the bottom. Also, do I use the same font family for legacy?

Comment: @wuhoo If you `\usepackage[ttdefault]{anonymouspro}` instead of `\usepackage[ttdefault]{newtxtt}`, you can use Anonymous Pro as a legacy font. The legacy package does not, unfortunately, support Greek, so you would need to do some extra work if you need Greek letters.

Comment: @wuhoo if the parser can’t find `\begin{document}`, there’s probably some unclosed `{` or `[` in the preamble. Make sure you copied the code correctly.

Comment: Man, I'm really struggling right now. I changed the code to {anonymouspro} under LaTeX but now it's just telling me that it can't find the file for the font. I don't know how to install it/I can't find the TeX directory on my mac. When I try to use XeTeX instead, it can't find the font either but I thought the font would be automatically installed. Also, is there a way to chat some other way than on stackexchange? I don't have enough reputation to move the discussion and don't really have the knowledge to answer many of the questions on this board to increase my rep...

Comment: @wuhoo here's my advice, then: Use the XeTeX version. Download the `.ttf` font files from the link I gave you above. Double-click them to install them as system fonts. They apparently were not installed for you already, but they're free.

Comment: @wuhoo If you're still stuck, and you run Snow Leopard or later, replace "Anonymous Pro" with "Menlo" or "Andale Mono". Every Mac should have those.

Comment: Installation seemed to clear up the entire list of problems it seemed to be encountering! Now the only error I'm getting is asking me if I have installed latex and dvipng/dvisvgm but I think that's the problem the redditor in the link I posted above was having.

Comment: I redirected to xelatex, dvipng, and dvisvgm under the command-line (http://www.jasoncantarella.com/wordpress/anki-2-022latexmavericks-problems-and-solutions/) like in this link, but it's still asking me the same question...

Comment: @wuhoo I'm not familiar with the program you're using, so you might want to ask that as a separate question where someone who is will see it.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you so much for all your help thus far! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89176/discussion-between-wuhoo-and-davislor).